# what's the difference between Syntactic consequence ⊢ and Semantic consequence ⊨

Tags: logic

Can you help me to differentiate the Syntactic consequence $\vdash$ and Semantic consequence $\vDash$ ?

I think  $A \vdash B$  means,  "$A$ proves $B$" and  $A \vDash B$  means , if $A$ is true, then $B$ is true.

If so, what is difference $A \to B$  and  $A\vDash B$   ?

Comment: Have you tried searching the site? This question looks awfully familiar as if it was asked twice or more before.

Comment: E.g.: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90787/whats-the-difference-between-to-implication-and-vdash-therefore and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286077/implies-vs-entails-vs-provable and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-symbol-models; and while not directly this question another very related question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105575/what-is-the-difference-between-completeness-and-soundness-in-first-order-logic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$A \vdash_S B$ means there is a derivation, in the proof-system $S$, from the premise $A$ to the conclusion $B$. [If context fixes the relevant system $S$ we suppress the subscript.]

$A \vDash_L B$ means that on every possible interpretation of the non-logical vocabulary of language $L$, if $A$ comes out true, so does $B$.  [If context fixes the relevant language $L$ we suppress the subscript.]

Both those are **metalinguistic** claims, the symbolism abbreviating mathematical English (or mathematical Spanish, or whatever), making claims about the relation between the well-formed formulas (wffs) $A$ and $B$, looking from the outside of their formal language, so to speak.

$A \to B$, by contrast, is a wff that belongs to the **object language**, to the formal language of which $A$ and $B$ are wffs (typically, but far from always, interpreted as expressing the truth-functional conditional).

On the truth-functional interpretation, if the atomic wff $p$ happens to be false and the atomic wff $q$ happens to be false too, then $p \to q$ evaluates as true. But of course we don't have $p \vDash q$ ($q$ isn't true on every valuation which makes $p$ true).

And so it goes ......

[Oh, I seem to have said much the same before, in slightly different words, at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286077/implies-vs-entails-vs-provable, so check that out too to see whether that helps as well.]

Comment: Peter, as a footnote to your answer, I already pointed to the linked thread in my comment and have suggested it as a duplicate.

Comment: Ah: I just went onto auto-pilot when I saw the qn: that's what forty years of giving intro logic lectures does for you ... Sad, eh?

Comment: As a footnote to your comment, I can relate! :-)